# Trying to create a jquery/javascript function to switch displayed div, glitches when switching backwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So in the html I am using bootstrap's jumbotron styled divs. A page is displayed then when you click a button an Onclick action calls the function `flipPage({switch from page #},{switch to page #})`, and then theres the `flipBack({switch from page #},{switch to page #})`.

My problem is the animation gets screwed up , it'll repeat or switch to the wrong page and I don't know enough about jQuery animation to see if I'm doing something wrong. any tips or help would be much appreciated! I believe it is calling the wrong function? is that possible? It might be switching up the buttons?

For the error if you get the code running it, usually occurs when you go from page `1->2 , 2->3, 3->2, 2->1`. It'll load page 3 instead of going back to 1.

Link to DropBox Full of working code : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xtc2jj8m39k3ax3/AAApy9zwjgV5eVBPMktF_ehTa

**CSS: (using twitters bootstrap.css)**

```
.jumbotron.page1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 25%;
}
.jumbotron.page2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 150%;
}
.jumbotron.page3{
    position: absolute;
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 150%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="container">
     <div id="page1" class="jumbotron page1" style="">
         <h1 style="text-align:center; width:564px">Welcome to page 3</h1>
         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  onClick="flipPage(1,2)"> Next Page</button>
     </div>

   <div id="page2" class="jumbotron page2" style="">
         <h1 style="text-align:center; width:564px">Welcome to page 2</h1>
          <button  class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick="flipPage(2,3)">Next Page ></button>
         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  onClick="flipBack(2,1)"> Back</button>
     </div>


     <div id="page3" class="jumbotron page3" style="">
         <h1 style="text-align:center; width:564px">Welcome to page 3</h1>
         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  onClick="flipBack(3,2)"> Back</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
      $('#page2').hide();
      $('#page3').hide();
function flipPage(fromPage,toPage)
          {


              var fromPage = "#page"+ fromPage;
              var toPage = "#page"+ toPage;
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $(fromPage).click(function() {

                $(fromPage).animate({left: '-150%'}, 500, function() {
                      $(fromPage).hide();   
                      $(toPage).show().animate({left: '25%'},200, function(){
                         });
                      });
                });

             });
           }

       function flipBack(fromPage,toPage)
          {

              var fromPage = "#page"+ fromPage;
              var toPage = "#page"+ toPage;
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $(fromPage).click(function() {
                $(fromPage).animate({left: '150%'}, 500, function() {
                      $(fromPage).hide();  
                      $(toPage).show().animate({left: '25%'},200, function(){
                      });;
                 });
            });

         });

         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. Hopefully, it's the functionality you are after:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <meta name="description" content="">
   <meta name="author" content="">
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="css/favicon.ico">
   <title>DeskOS</title>
   <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="css/favicon.ico" />

   <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
   <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- JavaScript -->
   <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <style>
    .jumbotron.page1{
        position: absolute;
        width: 750px;
        height: 500px;
        top: 100px;
        left: 25%;
    }
    .jumbotron.page2{
        position: absolute;
        width: 750px;
        height: 500px;
        top: 100px;
        left: 150%;
    }
    .jumbotron.page3{
        position: absolute;
        width: 750px;
        height: 500px;
        top: 100px;
        left: 150%;
    }
</style>

   <!-- Custom styles for this template -->



   </head>

   <div class="container">
         <div id="page1" class="jumbotron page1" style="">
             <h1 style="text-align:center; width:564px">Welcome to page1</h1>
             <button class="btn btn-primary forward" type="button" data-next="2" data-current="1"> Next Page</button>
         </div>

       <div id="page2" class="jumbotron page2" style="">
             <h1 style="text-align:center; width:564px">Welcome to page 2</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary forward" type="button" data-next="3" data-current="2">Next Page ></button>
             <button class="btn btn-primary back" type="button"  data-back="1" data-current="2"> Back</button>
         </div>


         <div id="page3" class="jumbotron page3" style="">
             <h1 style="text-align:center; width:564px">Welcome to page 3</h1>
             <button class="btn btn-primary back" type="button"  data-back="2" data-current="3"> Back</button>
         </div>
    </div>
<!-- /container --> 


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page2').hide();
    $('#page3').hide();
    $('.forward').click(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        flipPage($this.data('current'), $this.data('next'));
    });
    $('.back').click(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        flipBack($this.data('current'), $this.data('back'));
    });
     function flipPage(fromPage,toPage)
     {
        var fromPage = "#page"+ fromPage;
        var toPage = "#page"+ toPage;

        $(fromPage).animate({left: '-150%'}, 500, function() {
                $(fromPage).hide();   
                $(toPage).animate({left: '25%'},200, function(){}).show();
        });

    }

    function flipBack(fromPage,toPage)
    {
        var fromPage = "#page"+ fromPage;
        var toPage = "#page"+ toPage;

        $(fromPage).animate({left: '150%'}, 500, function() {
            $(fromPage).hide();   
            $(toPage).animate({left: '25%'},200, function(){}).show();
        });
    }
});
   </script>


</html>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity how did you get it to work? what is the data-back and data-current accomplish?

Comment: The data properties are used to pass in the current state and the page you are trying to flip to. Everything is wrapped in the .ready function to bind click events when the dom is ready. The logic you wrote was fine. Now you just need the forward or back class on an element for the click event to work

Comment: Thank you learned something new! Im going to add this to my git so that others can use the code, I have made it even more generic, I would like to include your name as a thanks. Well If it is fine by you!

Answer (score 1):

so:

http://jsfiddle.net/R6qwX/22/embedded/result/

Changes I made:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- the container: -->
<div id="pages-container" class="container" data-current-page="1">

<!-- each 'next' button: -->
<button class="btn btn-primary next-page-btn" type="button"> Next Page</button>

<!-- each 'back' button: -->
<button class="btn btn-primary back-page-btn" type="button"> Back</button>
```

**CSS:**
no '`left: 25%`' or 150%.

```
body {
    overflow-x:hidden; // hide the buttom scroll bar
}
```

**js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // drop the pages to left * 10000
    $('#page2').css({left: $('#page2').offset().left * 10000});
    $('#page3').css({left: $('#page3').offset().left * 10000});
});
```

*function to next page:*

```
function nextPage(from, to) {
    var currentPageLeft = $( "#page" + from ).offset().left;
    $( "#page" + from ).animate({left: '-' + currentPageLeft * 10000}, 500);

    var nextPageLeft = $( "#page" + to ).offset().left;
    $( "#page" + to ).animate({left: nextPageLeft / 10000}, 300, function() {
        $( "#page" + to ).css({left: 'auto'});
    }); 
}
```

*function to back page:*

```
function backPage(from, to) {
    var currentPageLeft = $( "#page" + from ).offset().left;
    $( "#page" + from ).animate({left: currentPageLeft * 10000}, 500);

    var backPageLeft = $( "#page" + to ).offset().left;
    $( "#page" + to ).animate({left: backPageLeft / -10000}, 300, function() {
        $( "#page" + to ).css({left: 'auto'});
    });
}
```

*click on 'next page':*

```
$( ".next-page-btn" ).click(function() {
    // get current page number
    currentPage = parseInt($( "#pages-container" ).attr('data-current-page'));
    nextPage(currentPage, currentPage + 1);
    // update current page number
    $( "#pages-container" ).attr('data-current-page', currentPage + 1);
});
```

*click on 'back':*

```
$( ".back-page-btn" ).click(function() {
    // get current page number
    currentPage = parseInt($( "#pages-container" ).attr('data-current-page'));
    backPage(currentPage, currentPage - 1);
    // update current page number
    $( "#pages-container" ).attr('data-current-page', currentPage - 1);
});
```

### demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R6qwX/22/

Comment: Thank you for all the effort! Your code just doesn't do the slide as I need it to be done. But I learned a lot from observing the changes you made, some real interesting stuff you did.